# Thread-safe way of incrementing value for specific key in a map inside another map

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety

So, I have one map inside another one, for example, it might be word-counter per account base:

```
Map<Long, Map<String, Long>>
```

What is proper thread-safe way to increment the counter?

I guess it's possible to use ConcurrentHashMap and LongAdder like following:

```
private Map<Long, Map<GovernorLimitName, LongAdder>> status = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();

public void count (Long accountId, String word) {
  status.putIfAbsent (accountId, new ConcurrentHashMap<GovernorLimitName, LongAdder> ());
   synchronized (getStatus ().get (accountId)) {
     getStatus ().get (accountId).computeIfAbsent(limitName, k -> new LongAdder()).increment();
   }
 }
```

I believe that syncronyzation here is required cause of race condition between getting inner map and performing comuteIfAbsent() on it, is that correct?

**Updated**

I assume that both submaps and adders might be removed, cause there might be other methods accessing that map.

Comment: How about using an AtomicLong

Comment: ConcurrentHashMap should be threadsafe in itself and allow manipulating in a thread-safe manner...

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz, The `ConcurrentHashMap` instances can be safely accedded by multiple threads, but we don't know whether the `LongAdder` class is thread safe.  The code still might need a `synchronized` block around the `.increment()` call.

Comment: Personally, I would hide the LongAdder - the whole map actually - behind some class, so that you have only specific places where it can be accessed, which makes synchronzing so much easier...

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in using `ConcurrentHashMap` if you need to synchronize and you're right that you do because you're getting the value: `Map<GovernorLimitName, LongAdder>` (which *is* done concurrently) and then fetch `LongAdder` and increment it (which is *not*).

Instead of using `Long` use [`AtomicLong`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicLong.html) and change the implementation to use a regular HashMap.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the `synchronized`, as long as submaps are never removed from `status`, and adders are never removed from the submaps.

Creating a new ConcurrentHashMap that you will usually throw away is too expensive, though.  Using the data structures you already have, you can do it like this:

```
public void count (Long accountId, GovernorLimitName limitName) {

  Map<GovernorLimitName, LongAdder> submap = status.computeIfAbsent(accountId,
     a -> new ConcurrentHashMap<GovernorLimitName, LongAdder> ());

  LongAdder adder = submap.computeIfAbsent(limitName, k -> new LongAdder());

  adder.incremeent();
}
```

Comment: Actually, both submaps and adders are removed. I assumed this by default. My fault.

Comment: @san -- be careful if that is so, since just about everything you can do with these statistics would be broken by values disappearing.

Answer (score 0):

instead of using *putIfAbsent* on main map, just use *compute* function (and do everything inside that function, even the inner map stuff). Whatever you do inside the function will be thread-safe if using ConcurrentHashMap in the root map; no need for synchronization block if you do it this way.

obviously, you will still need concurrenthashmap with this approach (in both) since i guess you will be doing gets at some other point of your code, and otherwise you would have concurrency issues while reading data.

other approaches could be taken instead of using ConcurrentHashMap's, but that's out of the scope of the question and it's fine to use those implementations.

Here you have some code (might have typos, and codestyle can be improved):

```
private Map<Long, Map<GovernorLimitName, LongAdder>> status = new ConcurrentHashMap<> ();

public void count (Long accountId, String word) {
    status.compute(accountId, (k, v) -> {
        if (v == null) {
            v = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        }
        v.compute(limitName, (k2, v2) -> {
            if (v2 == null) {
                v2 = new LongAdder();
            }
            v2.increment();
            return v2;
        });
        return v;
    });
 }
```